# Create sublists of indexes of equal values from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to split a list of integers into sublists of the the indexes of equal integers. So say I have a list:

```
original_list = [1,2,1,4,4,4,3,4,4,1,4,3,3]
```

The desired output would be:

```
indexes : [[0,2,9], [1], [6,11,12], [3,4,5,7,8,10]]
# corresponds to sublists: [[1,1,1] [2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4,4,4,4]]
```

I can't figure out how to do this though, as most solutions require you to first sort the original list, but in my case, this messes up the indices. Itertools or np.arrays have not helped me for this reason, as they only group sequential equal elements.

Does anyone know of a solution for this problem? I would love to hear!

Comment: FYI, there's a suitable sort function in numpy for this: [argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
original_list = [1,2,1,4,4,4,3,4,4,1,4,3,3]
groups = {a:[i for i, c in enumerate(original_list) if c == a] for a in set(original_list)}
```

Output:

```
{1: [0, 2, 9], 2: [1], 3: [6, 11, 12], 4: [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), you can build a mapping of values to their indices with

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for index, value in enumerate(original_list):
    dd[value].append(index)

print(dd)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [0, 2, 9], 2: [1], 4: [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10], 3: [6, 11, 12]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for a one-pass solution. Then use `sorted` if you need, as in your desired result, to sort your indices by value.

```
original_list = [1,2,1,4,4,4,3,4,4,1,4,3,3]

from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

dd = defaultdict(list)

for idx, value in enumerate(original_list):
    dd[value].append(idx)

keys, values = zip(*sorted(dd.items(), key=itemgetter(0)))

print(keys, values, sep='\n')

(1, 2, 3, 4)
([0, 2, 9], [1], [6, 11, 12], [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10])
```

For comparison, the values of `dd` are *insertion* ordered in Python 3.6+ (officially in 3.7+, as a CPython implementation detail in 3.6):

```
print(list(dd.values()))

[[0, 2, 9], [1], [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10], [6, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it with numpy, using the argsort function I linked in the comments.

```
original = [1,2,1,4,4,4,3,4,4,1,4,3,3]
indexes = []
s = set()

for n in np.argsort(original):
    if original[n] in s:
        indexes[-1].append(n)
    else:
        indexes.append([n])
        s.add(original[n])

print(indexes)
```

Comment: clever use of the set to keep track of what you have seen. Python's sorted can be swapped for numpy's without sacrificing performance (in the big Oh sense), besides it returns a new list so the first isn't modified. Good work.

Comment: @xerosmith You actually can't swap Pythons sort function because [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) does something else. It returns the indexes of the elements rather than the elements themselves. Also, it doesn't modify the original list.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a list comprehension.

```
>>> x = [1,2,1,4,4,4,3,4,4,1,4,3,3]
>>> [[i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i]==y] for y in sorted(set(x))]
[[0, 2, 9], [1], [6, 11, 12], [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]]
```

Comment: Not to nitpick here, but the time complexity of this is pretty bad.

Comment: @ninesalt lol, and you did just that. Nevertheless, in a situation such as this, the comprehension suffices because it is a one off thing. If you had to do something like this over and over, you should use to a different data structure. 

Premature optimisation is unnecessary moreover, for small lists (even up to a few thousand elements), the actual execution time of this will be so small that this solution works fine. 

It is correct, compact, and works just fine. I quite like the answer from Ajax1234 as well. But hey, array indexing is constant time eh?

Comment: I get what you're saying but you shouldn't be doing it the "bad" way until you need to improve it, even if it *is* a one off thing. OP didn't mention complexity so it obviously doesn't matter in this case, that was just a side note. Also, take a look at my answer.

Comment: But that's the thing, this is not "the bad way". In fact, starting from a a correct solution and incrementally improving the optimising the solution whilst maintaining correctness is a very very important method of deriving a program from specifications. This method is espoused by the likes of Donald Knuth, Richard Bird and several others. See  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird%E2%80%93Meertens_formalism